# Прикрепить файл к БД Access на Python

Tags: python, access, odbc, sql

Всех приветствую.
Есть пакет **pypyodbc**. Однако я не могу понять, каким образом следует сформировать SQL-like запрос, чтобы к базе данных MS Access **прикрепить** файл.

Можно сделать ссылку:

`record[u'Ссылка на файл'] = u'#' + folder_path + u'\\' + unicode(file_name)  + u'#'`

Однако я хочу именно прикрепить в Эксесе файл.

Вопрос уже задавал здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262341/attach-file-into-access-database-using-python

Comment: что значит *"к базе данных MS Access прикрепить файл"*? залить BLOB в таблицу?

Comment: Насколько я помню, проще создать в системе (в панели управления) источник данных ODBC для Вашей .mdb и потом его уже открывать в питоне